Is it possible to calculate the effective rate/cost from multiple rates?
Not sure if there is actually an answer to my question which relates to the cost of electricity.  Data extracted from an electricity bill is as follows:



Description
Quantity
Rate
Total Cost $




Step 1
313.72 kWh
14.542 c/kWh
45.62


Step 2
8.79 kWh
30.690 c/kWh
2.70


TOTAL
322.51 kWh
?      c/kWh
48.32



The Rate does not change no matter the Quantity used.  If I simply calculate the average, yes, I get an average rate of 14.982 c/kWh.  But when the Quantity changes (in the next bill), that average rate will no longer be correct.  What I want is to get a SINGLE Rate that would apply to ANY Quantity, whilst taking into consideration the 2 different rates.
I do apologise if I cannot make myself any clearer, though I hope I have done so sufficiently above.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

What do the steps mean? The Rate is clearly changing, so how to determine what the Rate is for the next bill?

What do you mean when you say you want a single rate that “takes into consideration the 2 different rates”?

"The Rate does not change no matter the Quantity used." According to the cited data, this statement is false. Why do you think it is true? Note that it is very common for a utility to charge one rate for usage up to some amount and a much higher rate for the remaining usage.
